# Не могу импортировать базу данных. Экспортировал базу с одного ПК и просто переношу ее на другой

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экспортировал базу данных в phpmyadmin (OpenServer), затем пытаюсь ее импортировать на другом ПК. Выходит такая ошибка... В чем проблема? Там база-то 5кБ и некоторые таблицы пустые.

Comment: Попробуйте вручную создать базу, выбрать ее, и уже там нажать импорт вашего файла

Comment: Да, помогло! Спасибо!